# AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient is not providing data on put

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient, with Dynamodb local (port 8080). When I perform a put, the `data` variable in the callback is an empty object. Have I missed something?

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";


AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8080"
});


const docClient: any = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


const item = {
      someField:    "456",
      other:         "123"
};

const params = {
  TableName: "TableName",
  Item: item
};

docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data); // this produces: {}
});
```

There is no error, and the item is being inserted\updated - however the `data` variable is an empty object. Shouldn't this contain values?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't asking for any values to come back, so why do you expect there to be any values coming back? You'll need to set the appropriate parameters `ReturnConsumedCapacity` and/or `ReturnItemCollectionMetrics` and/or `ReturnValues` if you are wanting any of that to come back in the response.

Comment: So what is the correct syntax to get put() to return the inserted object or some of its attributes?

Comment: @DangerGinger Review the Parameters documentation on the DocumentClient page for details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#put-property

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti, I did do that and eventually found the solution.  I googled this question and this answer is a good hint but does not provide a specific solution to OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

As you can't set a value for "ReturnValues" that actually returns anything useful, I worked around it by simple passing back the original item data that was passed in.

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";


AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8080"
});


const docClient: any = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


const item = {
      someField:    "456",
      other:         "123"
};

const params = {
  TableName: "TableName",
  Item: item
};

// Have a clear reference to this scope
var self = this;

docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(self.params.Item); // this should return the data you passed in!
});
```

I set "self" as "this" to make it clear where I'm reading the data from. Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

To clarify accepted answer a bit.

Set the return value as:

```
var params = {
  Item: data,
  TableName: 'myTable',
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_OLD'
}
```

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) specify:

`NONE` - If ReturnValues is not specified, or if its value is NONE, then nothing is returned. (This setting is the default for ReturnValues.)

`ALL_OLD` - If PutItem overwrote an attribute name-value pair, then the content of the old item is returned.

Note: The ReturnValues parameter is used by several DynamoDB operations; however, PutItem does not recognize any values other than `NONE` or `ALL_OLD`.

This effectively means as the answer by Walter White describes that unless there is an update to an existing item that nothing will be returned.